# two processes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, timer

First of all I should say that I have no relevant experience in VBA but I badly need to make a timer in excel. I have managed to create stop and start buttons of the timer. But I have 20 different timers with start and stop buttons. I want to create a button that will be automatically start all timers while letting me stop individually a single timer.

I have produced the following code to start and stop them. But when I stop one of the timers I get the following error:"Run-time error '1004': Method 'onTime' of object'_application failed.

The code for the two start and stop buttons is:

```
Sub startTimer27()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Increment_count27"
End Sub

Sub Increment_count27()
Range("B2").Value = Range("B2") + 1
Range("B11").Value = Range("B11") + 1
Range("B19").Value = Range("B19") + 1
Range("B25").Value = Range("B25") + 1
Range("B33").Value = Range("B33") + 1
startTimer27
End Sub

Sub stopTimer27()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Increment_count27", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: have a dropdown with all timer names and  "All Timers"  , have 2 buttons linked to 2 functions -start and stop that take a parameter of the name of the timer   start(sTimer as String)  as example

Comment: What do you mean by dropdown? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Data Validation , set to List and supply a range for the timer names ,  then the function will be passed the cell vaue containing the dropdown list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using global variables saving the current time value?

```
Sub startTimer27()
starttime = Now
'MsgBox("The timer is running.")
End Sub

Sub stopTimer27()
timetaken = Now - starttime
MsgBox ("The time elapsed is " & Hour(timetaken) & ":" & Minute(timetaken) & ":" & Second(timetaken))
End Sub
```

Of course with your example it would be more like:

```
Public starttime(1 To 20) As Date
Sub cvbstartTimer27()
For i = 1 To 20
    starttime(i) = Now
Next
End Sub
```

If you need to specifically stop it, then you'd have to give it a Boolean value too, that would be true when the timer is running and false when it's stopped.  The lack of this value doesn't mean your code is wrong nevertheless.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use Format(timetaken,"HH:mm:ss") in your MsgBox line?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am very unexperienced in VBA that's why I do not really consider anything. I will try it. Thanks